# Image stored as PFFile is not being saved - How do I ensure it gets saved eventually without freezing my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform, pffile

As the title says, I have an image that I'm saving as a PFFile and trying to attach to an object. About 5% of the time, it doesn't save properly, which kind of sucks. I've reduced the size by a factor of 4, which helped a lot, but I can't reduce it much more without sacrificing too much quality.

We have service providers who need to start going to their next job, so I can't just freeze them until the PFFile uploads. The issue is that they are in areas with poor cell signal. I don't know if it's getting cut off, or if it's just taking longer than the 3 seconds beforeSave allows before saving, but I need to find a solution to this.

Right now, I'm creating the imageFile from the image, attaching it to a PFObject, then saving that object in the background. I know that I could add a block that sees if the save was successful, and if not, retry the save until it is, but as I said earlier, I don't want to freeze our providers until they get somewhere with enough service to get the save to go through.

Is there a good way to create a background thread that attempts to save until the save is successful without being noticed by the main thread?

One tricky bit may be that the view controller gets popped off as soon as the provider leaves their "job completed" view after where I try uploading this photo. However, I use an SWRevealViewController, so if I could somehow pass this PFFile to that other view controller before it's been successfully saved to a file, that would be ideal...

Thanks for any tips and advice!

Comment: PFFile should have `-saveEventually`. Don't they support it yet? I am pretty sure you can `pin` file and easily save it in background.

Comment: If PFFile has its own saveEventually, I haven't found it. The only way I saw to save a PFFile is by attaching it to an object. Right now I'm using saveEventually on the object I attach it to, but when that fails, nothing happens. I want to make it so that when it fails, it tries again.